# How to ungroup created from instance?

Tags: add-on, instances

With the help of [quick instances addon](https://m-soluyanov.gumroad.com/l/qinstance)

[image]

[image]

Created the rack and group.
I have copied the object and pasted in new file. Know i want to ungroup the object. Why im unable to ungroup or how to ungroup it, Any suggestion or help. Thanks

Comment: Object > Apply > Make instances real ?

Comment: @Gorgious Thanks, really i was stuck in middle